# how to use Amazon Product Advertisting API on behalf of a seller

Tags: api, product, ads, amazon-product-api

Scenario: I have a user with an Amazon account. They have a website they would like to advertise on (Amazon Affiliate). They have signed up and registered their account for Amazon's Product Advertising API. They have their access id and access secret and I can successfully use their access keys to look up items

However I know it's not best practice to use the users' access tokens and I have got them to create a separate user with my own access keys, created through Amazon's Identity Access Management console. However when I use them to query Amazon for items it returns

"Your AccessKey Id is not registered for Product Advertising API. Please use the AccessKey Id obtained after registering at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/flex/advertising/api/sign-in.html."

Is there no way to use my access tokens from the IAM system to be somehow linked to the users' registered account (which can already access the Product API)?

Note: the user created was given Full Administrator Access in the User Policies, yet Amazon still requests the user accesskey id to be registered specifically to the Product Advertisting API

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be similar to the issue I just spent 2 weeks working through. Amazon has some odd stuff going on at the back of the API accounts.

I suspect your issue (if you have not already figured it out) is that the ID you have tied to the Product API codes does not match whatever Amazon has activated for that ID (or vice-versa).

---

I had a multiple accounts problem.

My company has 2 accounts 
- a Consignment Account for print books which we have had since 1998 (Amazon Advantage)
- an Advertising Account for site display ads and linkage for sales (Amazon Associates)

The log in for both accounts was the same -- but at different URLs. No problem.

Amazon provides ONE URL for the Web services (API) log in. They don't check if you are already logged in (as I was to my Advertising account). They don't retain a current login; they just present another separate log in box for the AWS section.

THAT'S WHAT CREATED THE PROBLEM.

I logged in with my credentials. My dashboard showed I was signed up for the API service. I retrieved the Product API codes. They did not work. Why? The account Amazon had linked to those API codes was my Print books account. They had not activated it for use with the Product API / advertising service. (even though it shows as active, it's not....)

The solution:

I changed my log ins -- to manually separate the accounts -- one for the Advertising / AWS login and one for my print books account. Both accounts are active and both show as signed up for the Product API service and both appear to be working. In reality, only one works.

Test:

After shutting down all browsers, I opened the AWS Login page. This time, I logged in with the new credentials just created for the Advertising account.

I was provided with Product API codes (different from those for my Consignment account). Those codes were active and provide a working API connection.

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from [aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151500) and it worked..

"So, thanks to help from an internal legend, found a solution that resolved this for me. In the AWS management console navigate to 'Security Credentials' under the dropdown over your name (https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential). Under 'Access Keys' you can see your root access keys (the ones assigned to your root user created when you signed up with Product Advertising API). If you have 2 in there, delete one, then generate a new one. It will show you the proper AWS key and Secret Key. These paired with the proper Associate Tag should get you access to the API.

I could be spreading rumors, but don't believe you can hook users and groups under IAM Management Panel into Product Advertising API just yet....."

Comment: what about the associated tag value

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I deleted the account in question, dumped my cache. Started over completely. problem solved.